# Inserting Pandas Dataframe into MySQL table using Autoincrement to automatically generate primary key

Tags: python, mysql

I've a Pandas dataframe which I'm trying to insert into a MySQL table, using MySQLdb and to_sql. The table has 'allocationid' as primary key and autoincrement..  I will want to do this daily, deleting out the day's previous data from the MySQL table and reinserting updated data from the Pandas dataframe. Hence would like the primary key to autoincrement automatically (I won't be using it down the line, but may want to refer to it).

code is...

```
columns = ('date','tradeid','accountid','amount')
splitInput = pd.DataFrame(columns = columns)

splitInput['accountid'] = newHFfile['acctID']
splitInput['tradeid'] = newHFfile['Ref']
splitInput['amount'] = newHFfile['AMOUNT1']
splitInput['date'] = newHFfile['Trade Date']


db = MySQLdb.connect(host="(hostIP)", port=3306, user="user", passwd="(passwd)", db="(database)")

cursor = db.cursor()


query = """delete from  splittrades  where date = """ + runymdformat + """ """


cursor.execute(query)


db.commit()                            


splitInput.to_sql(con = db, name = 'splittrades',if_exists = 'append',flavor = 'mysql',index = False)

db.commit()   

db.close()
```

The problem is that without adding a column for primary key, I get 'OperationalError: (1364, "Field 'allocationid' doesn't have a default value")'

If I add a primary key column and leave it blank, null,  I get OperationalError: (1366, "Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'allocationid' at row 1")
If I use 1 or 0 in the allocationid column I get a duplicated value error msg.

MySQL usually auto-increments the primary key if you don't specify it - is there a way I can make this work from Python?

PS am not a Python expert so pls treat me gently - thanks :-)

Comment: PS also tried submitting lines individually.. for i in range(0,len(tradeIds)):
    tradeId = tradeIds[i]
    accountId = accountIds[i]
    amount = amounts[i]
    thisdate = dates[i]

    cursor.execute(''' insert into opssystem2.splittrades (tradeid, accountid, amount, date) values (%s,%s,%s,%s)''',(tradeId,accountId,amount,thisdate))

    db.commit()   but still doesn't autoincrement the primary key.. would much appreciate suggestions. thanks!!

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the same but with postgresql.